# Kendo DateTimePicker Block Form Submit Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In my form I use the DateTimePicker from Kendo UI. When I press the submit button the focus of the DateTimePicker is triggered and not the form submit event.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "NursingHome", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShortTimeCare, new { @class = "col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
                    @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.ShortTimeCare)
                          .Format("n0")
                          .Min(0)
                          )
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.ShortTimeCareForDate)
                      .Name("ShortTimeCareForDate")
                      .Value(DateTime.Now)
                      .Interval(15)
                  )
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

Have I forgotten something?

In my ViewModel I have a DateTime attribute.

```
public DateTime ShortTimeCareForDate { get; set; }
```

When I press the submit button the Curser jumps into the DateTimePicker Field. Nothing else happens.

When I change the code as following the submit event works as desired. (Maybe a Problem with the DateTime Attribute in the Model)

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
    @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker() // For(model => model.ShortTimeCareForDate)
        .Name("ShortTimeCareForDateXXXXX")
        .Value(DateTime.Now)
        .Interval(15)
     )
</div>
```

regards,
Marko

Comment: When you press a button the datepicker opens?? There has to be other code that is causing this

Comment: Sounds like behaviour from a Validation event. We need more code to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

When I use the english dateformat then it works. But I need the german format.

English:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.ShortTimeCareForDate)
    .Name("ShortTimeCareForDate")
    .Value(DateTime.Now)
    .Format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    .Interval(15)
)
```

German

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.ShortTimeCareForDate)
    .Name("ShortTimeCareForDate")
    .Value(DateTime.Now)
    .Format("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    .Interval(15)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use button  type="button" instead of using submit**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using the wrong culture either on the client or on the server side.

according to http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization you have to set the german culture like follows:

1. include the culture you want to use right under ~/Scripts/cultures/kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js
2. in your Layout.cshtml include the culture:

   ```
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cultures/kendo.culture.de-DE.min.js")"></script>
   ```
3. and set it afterwards:

   ```
   <script>
   kendo.culture("de-DE");
   </script>
   ```

if you want to set the culture on the server side you need to update your web.config like that:

```
<system.web>
 <globalization uiCulture="de-DE" culture="de-DE"></globalization>
</system.web>
```

this should fix the occurring issue